# What Listener, Transition and Scheduler do in Solid's internal API?

Tags: coding-style, solid-js

I'm reading Solid JS's source code, but I find that there's little comments from code. Solid is much simpler than React, but lots of comments can be found inside React's code. Why there is no comments or document for explaining key concepts?

Please can you explain what `Listener`, `Transition` and `Scheduler` do:

```js
let Listener: Computation<any> | null = null;
export let Transition: TransitionState | null = null;
let Scheduler: ((fn: () => void) => any) | null = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of comments does not necessarily mean lack of documentation but you are partly right as the internal API is not documented enough. I believe there are several contributing factors:

1. Core team is small and a large portion of the code is written by its creator, Ryan Carniato, and it is maintained by him.
2. There are not as many optimization tricks as in React code because Solid is fast enough. There are no corner cases and code is clean enough to read through, so most of the time code is the documentation.
3. Relatively young and evolving project. API stable but its ecosystem is not. It is not widely used in production apps. There are patterns and use cases to emerge. When project matures, it will be re-written and hopefully it will be better documented.
4. Some concepts require deep and elaborate discussions, others are inherently assumed. A few lines of comments is no place for an elaborate discussion and it would not be sufficient anyway for anyone who lacks the assumed knowledge.
5. There are long and detailed articles and screen casts on its core logic and design decisions.

Again, exposed API is well documented and has more than enough examples. Internal API is very small and clean enough to read.

Now, to explain the code snippet in the question:

Code belongs to signal's internal API.

Solid is a sync library. Code is executed synchronously and contrary to some other frameworks like React, you never cross async boundary. Point is Solid does not rely on the event loop for running batch updates but juggles code, meaning it pushes a signal's subscribers onto another variable, run state updates (series of assignments and data manipulations), get the stored variables back and notify the subscribers. Solid uses [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

In Solid each signal keeps its own data like subscribers list. There is no global subscribers queue.

`Listener` is used by the runtime to store a signal's subscribers temporarily during one of those code juggling and call them back. If I remember correctly runtime store a signal's listener in `Listener` then does its work. It is better understood in conjunction with a scheduler and batch updates.

`Transitions` are used for async consistency. They store state updates while a related asynchronous task is completed. Say you are rendering remote data tied to a query parameter like a page number. When you update the page number, an intermediate state will be crated and request will be sent but actual state update will be stored in transitions, which will run once the request settles down. Main idea is the page number and the rendered data that is tied to the page number always consistent. It is a form of batch updates but tied to async an async task.

You can read more about async consistency: https://dev.to/this-is-learning/why-all-the-suspense-understanding-async-consistency-in-javascript-frameworks-3kdp

`Scheduler` is used scheduling UI updates. In regular pub-sub model, subscribers are called back and chain of events are run at once and undisturbed. But it is not optimal if you have many moving pieces. Scheduler allows Solid runtime to switch tasks while running effects. By running effects I mean calling subscribers back.

Comment: This is a good reply however I would like to mention that Solid is actively used in production in a number of large-scale applications, though not as many as the older frameworks. Also Solid is not intending a complete rewrite but the reactivity core is being re-implemented currently to prepare for upcoming improvements. Solid is a mature framework and has been in development for 5 years. As more contributors onboard the implementation details will likely improve with time.

Comment: @ddibiase It is inception may go back 5 years but first commit was 3 years and 1.0 release was 2 years ago. Unfortunately adoption is unreasonably low at this point because there is no big corporate label behind it, people are sold to labels.  Its growth is organic and it is a good thing. Rewrite is not bad, all programs benefit from a re-write. Some even say a program has to be re-written regularly, after certain period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer @snnsnn. I Always read Solid acteact does.  I think Listener maybe something like an active effect but not sure about that. Transitions and Scheduler look like Batch Update and Async Scheduler in React. I'm heading to look into that. Just a little confused about how it works.

Comment: @WillerJonsam I see your are still confused. I improved the latter section, hope it clarifies some of your confusion.

Comment: @snnsnn the first commit was May 19 2018 but you are correct the 1.0 landed much later. Adoption is low but that shouldn't be confused with lack of maturity - those are slightly different topics. A big corporate brand name isn't critical for a framework, we can look at Preact, Vue and Svelte's success as an example of that. Regarding the rewrite point, just clarifying it's not in the plans not that it's a bad thing :)